# ckeditor rails gem adds base url to assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ckeditor, asset-pipeline, asset-sync

I am using this [CKEditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor): with Rails 4 and [assets_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) and Heroku
I get the following url:

```
http://www.baseurl.com//mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/ckeditor/config-77c214941cb7b15940a497f28f333f30.js
```

while it should be

```
//mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/ckeditor/config-77c214941cb7b15940a497f28f333f30.js
```

as defined in my assets_host

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

I also defined:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/ckeditor/";
```

But it doesn't help either.

**Why do I get baseurl?**

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading a ckeditor gem to version 4.0.11 fix this issue.